# Ionic 2 - How to show second dropdown data based on previous dropdown selection

Tags: typescript, drop-down-menu, ionic2

I am new to Ionic 2. I'm only have a surface basic of Ionic 2. I am trying to get a second dropdown based on the first selection. I already refer to the same problem but none of them using Ionic. Since I am new to Ionic 2, I dont know how to implement ionChange in Ionic 2. This is my part of code in .html

home.html

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>State</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="state">
    <ion-option *ngFor = "let state of states">{{state.name}}   
    </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>District</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="district">
    <ion-option *ngFor = "let district of districts">{{district.name}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let city of cities">
    <p>{{city.name}}</p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

home.ts

**Note:**
The actual data is many from the below data.

```
initializeState(){
  this.state = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Melaka'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Johor'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Selangor'}
  ];
}

initializeDistrict(){
  this.district = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Alor Gajah', state_id: 1, state_name: 'Melaka'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Jasin', state_id: 1, state_name: 'Melaka'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Muar', state_id: 2, state_name: 'Johor'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Segamat', state_id: 2, state_name: 'Johor'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Shah Alam', state_id: 3, state_name: 'Selangor'},
    {id: 7, name: 'Klang', state_id: 3, state_name: 'Selangor'}
  ];
}

initializeCity(){
  this.cities = [
    {id: 1, name: 'City of Alor Gajah 1', state_id: 1, district_id: 1},
    {id: 2, name: 'City of Alor Gajah 2', state_id: 1, district_id: 1},
    {id: 3, name: 'City of Jasin 1', state_id: 1, district_id: 2},
    {id: 4, name: 'City of Muar 1', state_id: 2, district_id: 3},
    {id: 5, name: 'City of Muar 2', state_id: 2, district_id: 3},
    {id: 6, name: 'City of Segamat 1', state_id: 2, district_id: 4},
    {id: 7, name: 'City of Shah Alam 1', state_id: 3, district_id: 5},
    {id: 8, name: 'City of Klang 1', state_id: 3, district_id: 6},
    {id: 9, name: 'City of Klang 2', state_id: 3, district_id: 6}
  ];
}
```

What I'm trying to do is first I want to get second dropdown based on the first dropdown. And then from both selection in first and second dropdown, I want to listing all the name of city.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a change event handler on the first select element. Then have that call a method, passing the selected value with it. Then do some checks on the selected values to determine if you want to show the next select and then the list.

```
*.html ------- template
<ion-content padding>
     <ion-item>
         <ion-label>State</ion-label>
         <ion-select (ionChange)="setDistrictValues(sState)"[(ngModel)]="sState">
             <ion-option [value]="sState" *ngFor="let sState of states">{{sState.name}} </ion-option>
         </ion-select>
     </ion-item>
     <ion-item *ngIf="selectedDistricts">
        <ion-label>District</ion-label>
        <ion-select (ionChange)="setCityValues(sDistrict)" [(ngModel)]="sDistrict">
            <ion-option [value]="sDistrict" *ngFor="let sDistrict of selectedDistricts">{{sDistrict.name}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
     </ion-item>
     <ion-list *ngIf="selectedCities">
         <ion-item *ngFor="let city of selectedCities">
              <p>{{city.name}}</p>
         </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
```

```
*.ts ------- controller/component
    public states: any[];
    public districts: any[];
    public cities: any[];

    public selectedDistricts: any[];
    public selectedCities: any[];

    public sState: any;
    public sDistrict: any;

    appName = 'Ionic App';

    constructor(public navController: NavController) { 
        this.initializeState();
        this.initializeDistrict();
        this.initializeCity();
    }

    initializeState(){
    this.states = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Melaka'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Johor'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Selangor'}
    ];
    }

    initializeDistrict(){
    this.districts = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Alor Gajah', state_id: 1, state_name: 'Melaka'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Jasin', state_id: 1, state_name: 'Melaka'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Muar', state_id: 2, state_name: 'Johor'},
        {id: 4, name: 'Segamat', state_id: 2, state_name: 'Johor'},
        {id: 5, name: 'Shah Alam', state_id: 3, state_name: 'Selangor'},
        {id: 7, name: 'Klang', state_id: 3, state_name: 'Selangor'}
    ];
    }

    initializeCity(){
    this.cities = [
        {id: 1, name: 'City of Alor Gajah 1', state_id: 1, district_id: 1},
        {id: 2, name: 'City of Alor Gajah 2', state_id: 1, district_id: 1},
        {id: 3, name: 'City of Jasin 1', state_id: 1, district_id: 2},
        {id: 4, name: 'City of Muar 1', state_id: 2, district_id: 3},
        {id: 5, name: 'City of Muar 2', state_id: 2, district_id: 3},
        {id: 6, name: 'City of Segamat 1', state_id: 2, district_id: 4},
        {id: 7, name: 'City of Shah Alam 1', state_id: 3, district_id: 5},
        {id: 8, name: 'City of Klang 1', state_id: 3, district_id: 6},
        {id: 9, name: 'City of Klang 2', state_id: 3, district_id: 6}
    ];
    }

    setDistrictValues(sState) {
        this.selectedDistricts = this.districts.filter(district => district.state_id == sState.id)
    }

    setCityValues(sDistrict) {
        this.selectedCities = this.cities.filter(city => city.district_id == sDistrict.id);
    }
```

Select your state, filter for only the districts that have a state_id that matches the selected state ID. The same thing is done for the cities.

Working version:
https://embed.plnkr.co/Qu1lL6PDIX2DTDGv01ZI/

Comment: Not working. It said error, cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: @Akmal didn't mean to use .length

Comment: its not error now but the output is not what I want. What I want is if I select 'Melaka' at first dropdown, it will only show 'Alor Gajah' and 'Jasin' in second dropdown. And if I select 'Alor Gajah' in second dropdown, and the list will only list 'City of Alor Gajah 1' and 'City of Alor Gajah 2'. Any idea @pezetter ?

Comment: Sorry if my question not clear. I already tried the latest updated from you. For the first dropdown its work but when I want choose for second dropdown, there are no listing district. I already changed your this.district.filter() to this.districts.filter() but also not working.

Comment: Okay. Sorry. I was doing all of that on my phone. Check out the plnkr link i just added to the post. All you would have to do now is add some checks for when the selected state changes, the template should reflect that while its happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131604/discussion-between-pezetter-and-akmal).