# dynamically select option ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework

I have 2 select in ionic 2 and i am able to dynamically populate the second based on the value selected in first. but i cannot set the selected default option after the population. i tried:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>City</ion-label>
    <ion-select  (ionChange)="setCity($event)">
      <ion-option selected >City1</ion-option>
      <ion-option >City2</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Zona</ion-label>
    <ion-select >
      <ion-option  *ngFor ="let location of locations[city]" 
                 [selected] = location.selected >
        {{location.zone}}
      </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

 in .ts

 this.locations = {'City1':[{ zone: 'Zone1', selected: true},{zone:'Zone2', selected: false}],
                  'City2': [{zone: 'Zone3', selected: false} {zone:'Zone4', selected: true}]}

 setCity(event){
    this.city = event;
 }
```

there is no selected value after the second ion-select is populated

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a change event handler on the first select element. Then have that call a method, passing the selected value with it. Then do some checks on the selected values to determine if you want to show the next select and then the list.

Check out this StackOverflow question [How to show second dropdown data based on previous dropdown selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338585/ionic-2-how-to-show-second-dropdown-data-based-on-previous-dropdown-selection)

Working version: https://embed.plnkr.co/Qu1lL6PDIX2DTDGv01ZI/

**UPDATE** Display Default selected item

You wanna display Default selected item then you need to add these few line in your **html page**

like that:

```
     <ion-label>District</ion-label>
 <ion-select (ionChange). ....
     <ion-option [value]="0" >select District</ion-option>
      <ion-option [value]="sDistrict" *ngFor = ...
</ion-select>
```

and add these line in your type script(.ts) file

```
export class HomePage {
 ....
sState: number = "0";
sDistrict: number = "0";
.....
}
```

> if you face any problem then let me know.

Comment: I have done this and it works like in the plnkr example . But in the second select there is no selected district (default selected item)

Comment: show your code, it is working in the plnkr example. you need full code??

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ngModel attribute in ion-select and value attribute in ion-option like below

```
<ion-label>Zona</ion-label>
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="mLocation" >
  <ion-option [value] = "location" *ngFor ="let location of locations[city]" 
             [selected] = location.selected >
    {{location.zone}}
  </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```