# ionic 3 dropdown menu

Tags: ionic3, dropdown

I am using ionic 3 and i was able to create dropdown based on last dropdown value. then, when i create a page for edit the form. that selected dropdown value does not appear there but value save on the database.  according to this- [Ionic 2 - How to show second dropdown data based on previous dropdown selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338585/ionic-2-how-to-show-second-dropdown-data-based-on-previous-dropdown-selection)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh0yo.png)